# Django stay on the same site after add item to cart and not append search url to another url

Tags: django

So i encounter 2 problem:

- First is i want to stay on the same site when add item to cart/favourite

  - The idea is when the user search the product name, there will be list of products in the `/search_result` and i want user can add product from this list to a favourite db, and still stay in `/search_result` so they can add another product.
- Second is when i use search bar in `/favourite` the `/search_url` append to it become `/favourite/search_url` make in invalid

My models:

```
class Favourite(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='FavouriteItem')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "scrape_favourite"

class FavouriteItem(models.Model):
    favourite = models.ForeignKey(Favourite, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "scrape_favouriteitem"
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.search, name="search"),
    path("search_result", views.search_result, name ="search_result"),
    path("form/", views.form_view, name="form"),
    path("products/", views.products_view, name="products"),
    path("sign-up", views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
    path('add-to-favourite/<int:product_id>/', views.add_to_favourite, name='add-to-favourite'),
    path('remove-from-favourite/<int:product_id>/', views.remove_from_favourite, name='remove-from-favourite'),
    path('favourite/', views.view_favourite, name='favourite'),
]
```

My views:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def add_to_favourite(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    favourite = Favourite.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)[0]
    favourite_item = FavouriteItem.objects.get_or_create(favourite=favourite, product=product)[0]


    # return redirect('/')

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def remove_from_favourite(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    favourite = Favourite.objects.get(user=request.user)
    try:
        favourite_item = favourite.favouriteitem_set.get(product=product)
        favourite_item.delete()
    except FavouriteItem.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    # return redirect('/favourite')

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def view_favourite(request):
    try:
        newForm = ProductNameForm()
        favourite = request.user.favourite
        print(favourite)
        favourite_items = FavouriteItem.objects.filter(favourite=favourite)
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=favourite_items.values_list('product', flat=True))
        return render(request, 'favourite.html', {'favourite_items': products, 'form':newForm})
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'favourite.html', {'favourite_items': [], 'form':newForm})
```

My search form:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block form %}
<div id="searchbar" class="d-flex flex-row">
    <form action="search_result" method=POST class="my-form input-group flex-nowrap bg-light mx-0 mx-lg-auto rounded p-1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% render_field form.name placeholder="Search product..." class+="form-control input-form"%}
        {% comment %} <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search product" name="search-input" class="form-control rounded"> {% endcomment %}
        {% comment %} <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> {% endcomment %}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```